# Integrate multiple same structure datasets in one database

Tags: neo4j, schema

I have 8 different datasets with the same structure. I am using `Neo4j` and need to query all of them at different points on the website I am developing. What would be the approaches at storing the datasets in one database?

One idea that comes to my mind is to supply for each node an additional property that would distinguish nodes of one dataset from nodes of the other ones. But that seems too repetitive and wrong for me. The other idea is just to create 8 databases and query them separately but how could I do that? Running each one in its own port seems crazy.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your datasets are in a tree structure, you could add a different root node to each of them that you could use for reference, similar to [GraphAware TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree). Another option (better than a property, I think) would be to differentiate each dataset by adding a specific label to nodes from that dataset (i.e. all nodes from "dataset A" get a `:DataSetA` label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datasets are in a tree structure, you could add a different root node to each of them that you could use for reference, similar to [GraphAware TimeTree](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree). Another option (better than a property, I think) would be to differentiate each dataset by adding a specific label to nodes from that dataset (i.e. all nodes from "dataset A" get a `:DataSetA` label)

I imagine that the specific structure of your dataset may yield other options. For example, if you always begin traversals of the dataset from a few set locations, you only need to be able to determine which dataset the entry points are a part of, because once entered, all traversals would be made within the same dataset <-- if that makes sense.

Comment: So, you mean I would have two labels for nodes? One to identify the dataset, another - to identify the actual type of node in the dataset? Is it possible in Neo4j upon doing import?

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko correct. Node's can have any number of labels. Though I hear you shouldn't use more than 5 on one node. And, since labels are an index, more labels take up more space. Querying on multiple labels also forces neo4j to perform a filtering operation. In your case, adding the additional label sounds appropriate. And ya, you can add multiple labels on inport (I'm assuming you mean CSV import). You can [read the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) to learn more about the import process.

Comment: Thank you! It is very helpful. I am left with the last issue: conflicting `ID`s. The point is that between the datasets the ids are the same for many nodes. So, seems like I need to append the dataset specific labels also to `ID`s.

Comment: Also, `LOAD CSV` does not work for me, only their `import` tool since my datasets are huge

Comment: In docs they do not mention how to create entities with two labels using their import tool.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko It sounds like you might be using these databases as "read only", in which case you can simply index on ID's rather than constrain the ID's to be unique. Otherwise, appending the database label to the end of the ID is probably the best move. Unfortunately, you can't constrain a property to be unique over two labels. Also, I've never used the import tool, but just jumping over to the docs, the first ["basic example"](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) shows applying two labels to a node

Comment: I do not think so. There is only one `:LABEL`. Could you copy-paste here what you mean?

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko "Along with these properties we also add the node labels ***Movie*** and ***Sequel***." (emphasis mine). `:LABEL` is not the label. It's just the "column type" (not an official term, I just made that up). For the third entry in that example `tt0242653,"The Matrix Revolutions",2003,Movie;Sequel` The labels are `Movie` and `Sequel`.

Comment: Note that commas `,` are separating the different import columns while a semi-colon `;` is used to separate the individual labels in the label column.